# Timer Elapsed Event with Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect

So I'm using the Kinect SDK to make an application, and it's going well! I'm trying to make a button take a picture, but I want the code taking the picture to be delayed so the people have time to pose. I've tried using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); but what happens is that the whole thing freezes (Yes I know that's what sleep does...) and it uses the first frame anyway. So now I'm trying to use a Timer and Timed Event, but keep getting errors due to the inability to make it static (Kinect thing).

```
public class Timer1
{
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public void Main()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
        //This is where the problem is. I'm getting "Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'KinectButton.MainWindow' via nested type 'KinectButton.MainWindow.Timer1'
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(takepicture);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Enabled = True;
    }
}

[private void takepicture(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapSource image = (BitmapSource)videoStream.Source;

    image.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy HHmmss") + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

private void button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here I'm also getting "'KinectButton.MainWindow.Timer1' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled'"
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here I'm getting "'KinectButton.MainWindow.Timer1' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled'" again...
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Well, let me know if you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a WPF app? I think you will want to use Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer instead

```
Private timer As New Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer

timer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1)
AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
timer.Start()

Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'do something
End Sub
```

yeah i know its vb but it should be easy to convert